# Where do I find the .apk file?

Tags: android, export, apk

I want to export an APK file so a friend can try my app that I've developed using Eclipse/ADT on his phone. How do I do this? I can't find a suitable option under Eclipse's export options, and searching for .apk on my drive didn't show anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the project folder location.
Go inside the `bin` folder.
You will find the `apk` there**.
Send your apk to your friend via mail or USB.
Using the adb.exe install the file to your device.

** - If you have successfully build the project.

Answer (score 5):

Right click your android project --> Android tools --> Export unsigned application package

Answer (score 4):

Have you right clicked the project and choosen Export->Android->Export Android Application? Just building the app in Eclipse does not create the apk.

Answer (score 1):

look in you workspace/ folder

rightclick your project and choose options. resource->location

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in an answer to a similar question [How do you compile an Android project into an .apk file in Eclipse without launching the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801491/how-do-you-compile-an-android-project-into-an-apk-file-in-eclipse-without-launc) , since Eclipse Indigo, building the project will not put your APK directly on the bin folder. You will have to run the emulator for it to generate the APK

If you want the APK to be generated on build time, you need to Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Android -> Build and uncheck "Skip packaging and dexing until export or launch" then restart Eclipse. (credits for @Andy Weinstein who answered it on the other question)

Answer (score 0):

Ah I just realised it was there! Still not used to windows 7!! It was in the root of the project's bin directory after all.