# How do you compile an Android project into an .apk file in Eclipse without launching the emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-emulator, apk

I'm just wondering because I have my own seperate method of getting it on my phone via my web server and the emulator is getting annoying popping up every time.

Answer (score 22):

I had a problem that it would not build an APK for me (without Running) after I installed the latest SDK and latest Eclipse (Indigo 371).

Try this:

Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Android -> Build and uncheck "Skip packaging and dexing until export or launch" then restart Eclipse.

Now when you do Build Project you should get an APK

Comment: Cool. I'll try this as soon as I get back on Eclipse!

Answer (score 5):

Do you use Eclipse with Android ADT plugin? If so, you can use Android Tools/Export Signed Application Package to build the app as apk file

Comment: Indeed I'm using the Eclipse + ADT plugin, but I don't see what you're talking about. Where's that option located?

Comment: I haven't gotten the chance to check this out, but I will as soon as I  start my next android project.

Comment: This is quite an exhausting process for something that Eclipse does automatically when you Run the project. Isn't there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I understand your question right, but you can create an .apk file without running by right clicking your project, and then selecting Export.
The Android Application option should be available to you.

Comment: This might be the answer. Let me try it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 3):

right click ur project -> select android tools -> and then select export unsigned application and save to a location. Done, ur apk is available

Answer (score 1):

On the commandline, if sdk/tools is in your $PATH: run `android update project -p .` at least once, followed by `ant release`

From Eclipse: if Project > Build Automatically is off, Project > Build Project.

The apk is built in the bin/ directory.

Comment: So what if `Project > Build Automatically` is on? Does that mean it gets built everytime I save?

Comment: Also, one last question. so doing `project > Build Project` will not automatically start the emulator, right? (sorry, haven't gotten back into Eclipse to test this yet)

Comment: It does exactly what it says.

Answer (score 1):

by default, eclipse compiles your code into .apk on the fly.
.apk is generated in bin directory if i rememered right.
This can be cancelled by Project->Build Automatically. then you can build it under the same menu.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but it didn't rebuild the apk file automatically or manually without running the emulator..

You have to make sure that there are no errors (warnings are okay) on any of your projects in the workspace!! after that, check the Build Automatically option in Project tab in Eclipse! from now on, Eclipse will automatically compile your project to apk all the tim

Answer (score 1):

I have just started practicing with eclipse and I tried copying and installing the apk file from the 'bin' directory, onto my nexus 4. It worked perfectly.

Comment: That works, but pressing the compile button still automatically starts the emulator, so this doesn't really address that problem.