# How to get .apk of Android application to distribute in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I just developed an Android app using Windows 7 + Eclipse. This app also uses `FacebookSDK` which i added as a library in my main application called **MyFBFriends**.

My application is running smooth in Android Virtual Device manager (AVD).

*Now i want to get the `.apk` file of my application from eclipse so that i can put it on my personal website

How should i proceed?

I looked for Google but different tutorials like using command prompt, sign-unsigned etc are confusing me. Some suggest to go to bin folder (after building app) and just copy .apk from there but i don't see any .apk there.

Also what about that `FacebookSDK` library i added? Will it come automatically in my .apk file? or is there any special procedure for libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the library will be "inside" the apk.

You can right click your project -> Android Tools -> Export Signed/Unsigned Application Package.

It should also be inside your bin folder after building it.

Answer (score 1):

Your FacebookSDK will comes automatically to the .apk file when you add this as library for your application. for .apk look at your bin folder in your workspace after building your app.

Comment: after starting AVD its showing .apk in bin folder. So i just pick .apk only? Nothing else?

Comment: you have work space right?, workspace means where your storing your applications in the system.go to that place and open your application folder and then copy .apk from bin folder..

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the eclipse and select export and follow the instructions. Read this tutorial on [how to export your application form Eclipse](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/publish-to-android-market/).

Yeap all the libraries you use will be added to the .apk file.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801491/how-do-you-compile-an-android-project-into-an-apk-file-in-eclipse-without-launc) should explain it. If The solution to your problem is not here tell me. I'll try to help you in another way.